# Check availability in the List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, list

Have the class

```
public class StopSignal
    {
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public int timeout { get; set; }
    }
```

Create:

```
public static List<StopSignal> SignalTimeOut;
SignalTimeOut = new List<StopSignal>();
```

Add some information:
DateTime.Now for example = 25.10.2015 04:30:00

```
SignalTimeOut.Add(new StopSignal(){time = DateTime.Now, symbol="AAPL", timeout=60});
```

How to make checking the availability of the symbol in List SignalTimeOut?

Make a request to the List, where we have item: 25.10.2015 04:30:00, AAPL, 60

For example DateTime.Now = 25.10.2015 05:25:00

1. If the difference between *25.10.2015 04:30:00* and *25.10.2015
   05:25:00* < *60* minutes then there is some action
2. If the difference between *25.10.2015 04:30:00* and *25.10.2015
   05:25:00* > *60* minutes then we remove this item
3. If the item is not in list, then another action

Comment: What is it you actually need _specific_ help with? You can use a timer to perform actions periodically. You can use methods in LINQ or the `List<T>` class itself to examine the contents of the list and manipulate those contents. What part of this is it _exactly_ that you are having trouble with? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: I assume there's a synchronization issue here, as it looks like a trading system that is going to be adding and checking new equities.  Might be worth looking into using a SynchronizedCollection.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PeterDuniho My question is in the middle `How to make checking the availability of the symbol in List SignalTimeOut?`

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a dictionary, using symbol as the key, or using the cache object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to handle this is to find the matching element in the list and process it with a few if statements.  Note this code assumes there can be at most one match.  If that is not the case, or if you need to check for errors, replace .SingleOrDefault() with e.g. .ToList() and check the number of elements in that list

```
var match = SignalTimeOut.Where(s => s.symbol == desiredSymbol).SingleOrDefault();

if (match == null)
{
    Action3();
}
else
{
    var age = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - match.time.Ticks);
    if (age.TotalMinutes() > 60)
        Action2();
    else
        Action1();
}
```